# How to have condition on ActiveRecord validation scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I want uniqueness validation to have a scope + a specific condition.
For example, I want to check email uniqueness among a single tenant.

Note I don't need the validation to happen conditionally (that is achieved with:)

```rb
validate :email, uniqueness: { scope: :tenant }, if: -> { my_condition }
```

Instead, I want the validation scope to match only specific records (filter records of my uniqueness check):

```rb
# when you check for uniqueness, only check on 'live' records (nil deleted_at)
validate :email, uniqueness: { scope: :tenant, # where deleted_at is nil }
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to use `conditions` argument in scope, that takes a proc/block

```rb
# user model
validate :email, uniqueness: { scope: :tenant, conditions: -> { where(deleted_at: nil) } }
```

If you are using PostgreSQL, don't forget you can also have conditions on your index :

```rb
# migration file
add_index :users, [:tenant_id, :email], unique: true, where: "deleted_at IS NULL"
```

> remember the where clause need to be PSQL condition, not rails ones

credits: The answer comes from https://github.com/grosser/soft_deletion/issues/31